# Memory warning in IMM of nx360-m4 server

Tags: memory

I have a nx360-m4 IBM server with 128GB RAM.
Recently, when I connect through the IMM, the following warning is shown:

[image]

I would be glad for any explanation on this warning.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[It indicates that the referenced memory DIMM is [probably] bad](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systemx/documentation/topic/com.ibm.sysx.7915.doc/W.58001.html).

IBM suggests verifying the seating and connection for the DIMM, checking for a firmware update, and if those things don't work, replacing the DIMM.